# Can C# implicit operator's be used to set a property?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use Implicit Operators to make using my library, a bit easier.

I know I can `get` the value implicitly, but not sure how to `set` the value, if it can be done easily.

Here's the pseduo code I'm thinking about in my head ...

```
public class Int32Notified : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static implicit operator int(Int32Notified value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and something I'm thinking about .. when using it....

```
public class Foo
{
    // Yeah, i've not wired up the event... (yet)
    public Int32Notified Age { get; set; }
}


...

// Creation and setting.
var foo = new Foo { Age = 10 };

// Getting
int age = foo.Age;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.. Just add another implicit operator that changes your `int` to `int32Notified`. For example: `public static implicit operator Int32Notified(int value)
 {
  return new Int32Notified
  {
   Value = value
  };
 }`

Comment: That would be my first shot, but this will create a new Int32Notified instance but won't wire PropertyChanged event wired from the old instance...

Comment: I think you have to do this inside your property accessors. You won't be able to do it with a cast operator.

Comment: So .. `implicit operator`'s are not a good usecase, here?

Comment: Correct. The operator is static, receives an int, and must output an `Int32Notified`. It has no way of accessing the old instance in order to update its value, or copy its event subscribers. And if it did, it would be a strange thing for a cast to do. It's just the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: probably off topic, but maybe you should suggest using [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) here.

Comment: @nozzleman I actually checked Fody out before I posted this (for due diligence). I don't want to take on an external reference.

Comment: @Pure.Krome basically, what your class is doing is replacing a .NET-type with a custom class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Where does that begin and end? Can you be sure that the users of your lib will ever only want to be notified when `int`-Properties change, or could it be that they also want to be notified in case of a `long`, `string`, `bool`etc. Do you really want to provide wrapper classes for all of those types? The alterative would be to require your users to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` themselves. Fody can help them **w/o creating an additional reference** (dll).

Comment: It's not really even clear to me what you're asking. Your question appears to concern itself simply with type conversion between `int` and `Int32Notified`. Which a) can be easily done and b) might not accomplish your actual goal. But the actual goal is poorly described. Instead of focusing on the type conversion aspect, why not ask your question in a way that addresses the broader problem you're trying to solve (apparently something to do with value-changed notifications, but it's not clear exactly what).

Comment: The goal is clearly described. He's trying to set the value property of the instance via an implicit cast because the = operator can not be overloaded.